# ModuleNotFoundError when importing local .py file

Tags: python

I've tried looking everywhere about this problem but I cannot find the solution. I am also new to Python so forgive me, but I am trying to import my local readMessages.py file into my TextReactions.py file. I've tried import readMessages, from readMessages import take_screenshot, but I still get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readMessages'.
Thank you for any help in advanced!

```
from readMessages import take_screenshot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Loads the .env file that resides on the same level as the script.
load_dotenv()

# Grab the API token from the .env file.
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

import requests
import json
import discord
import os, os.path
import pyautogui
class readMessages:
    os.system('cls')
    list = os.listdir('C://Users//gamer//Documents//Pythong//Screenshots')
    count = len(list)
    def retrieve_messages(channelid):
        print("MESSAGES BELOW:")
```

Comment: Idk why it posted like that but -----------------
from readMessages import take_screenshot
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Loads the .env file that resides on the same level as the script.
load_dotenv()

# Grab the API token from the .env file.
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
----------------------------
is the first program, the rest is the second program

Comment: can you show us the structure of your directory tree?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to import local modules, then you should add an `__init__.py` file in the directory of the python file you want to import. The `__init__.py` can be empty.

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. Can I ask what the init.py file does?

Comment: @Danny Le the `__init.py__` basically signifies that the .py file is a module and can be imported from other files, there's not much else to it. And btw welcome to Python!

Comment: Aaah I see, thank you! Glad to be here

Answer (score 0):

Python has to types of imports, global and relative.

With the statement:

```py
from readMessages import take_screenshot
```

You are trying a global import of a module present in your installed libraries.

You should try a relative import:

```py
from .readMessages import take_screenshot
```

If this does not work, your working directory is probably misconfigured, you should update it on your ide.

Comment: It looks like the above comment worked, but if I run into any issues Ill keep this in mind! Thank you

Comment: That's great! You should mark the comment as the answer that solved your problem.